# Click on grid element to show more elements flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have a list of contacts, wondering how to show only the first 5 and the 6ed element to be "show more" element which when clicked on would show the rest of the contacts.
I'm looking for advice on how to achieve this UI functional:
[image: Contact show more]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class Contact {
  final String name;

  Contact(this.name);
}

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {

  final contacts = [
    Contact("sahar"),
    Contact("Joe"),
    Contact("fo"),
    Contact("Fifo"),
    Contact("Moshe"),
  ];

  var _displayAll = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("contacts"),),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child:_gridContacts(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _gridContacts() {
    final size = _displayAll ? contacts.length : contacts.length - 2;
    final contactsWidget = List.generate(
        size, (index) => _contactItem(contacts[index]))
      ..add(_seeNoSeeMore());
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      childAspectRatio: 2/1,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      children: contactsWidget,);
  }


  Widget _contactItem(Contact item) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.person),
          Text(item.name),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _seeNoSeeMore() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: ()=>setState(()=>_displayAll = !_displayAll),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.person),
            Text(_displayAll?"hide":"Show all"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Notice:** for better performance don't use setState instead use state management or the native one streambuilder.